# How to build a responsive email template using a table structure

Tags: html-table, html-email, responsive

I've been reading and researching how to build a responsive email - the thing is I am building it using a table. I know tables are not responsive by nature; however, I've been reading up on responsive design, media queries, and such and I still cannot find a solution. Below is what I have so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I would like to learn how to make an email responsive.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Trident Email</title>
<style type="text/css">
@media (max-width: 480px){
 table,tbody,tr,td,img {
  display:block;
 }
 div#background {
   width: 400px;
  }
 table#container{
   width:300px;
 }
} 
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="background" style="background-color:#eeee00;padding:10px 0;margin:0 320px;">

 
 <table style="margin:0px auto;border-spacing:0px;border-collapse:collapse;text-align:center;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" align="center">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <table id="container" style="border-spacing:0px;border-collapse:collapse;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>
        <img src="http://enews.trident.edu/hs-fs/hub/336281/file-2384384346-jpg/Headers_Footers/Trident_is_Coming_to_Town.jpg?t=1446144504152" width="100%" style="vertical-align:bottom;">
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        <table style="border-spacing;0px;border-collapse:collapse;background-color:rgb(0,39,77);" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
         <tbody>
          <tr>
           <td></td>
         
          <tr>
           <td style="text-align:left;" width="65%">
            <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="10" width="100%">
             <tbody>
              <tr>
               <td>
                <div style="">
                <p><span style="color: #9c800d; font-family: helvetica;text-transform:uppercase;"><strong>Date:</strong></span></p>
                </div>
               </td>
               <td width="100%" style="text-align:left;">
                <div style="">
                 <p>
                  <span style="color: #9c800d; font-family: helvetica;"><strong>November 2, 2015</strong></span>
                 </p>
                </div>
               </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
               <td>
                <div style="">
                <p>
                 <span style="color: #9c800d; font-family: helvetica;text-transform:uppercase;"><strong>time:</strong></span>
                </p>
                </div>
               </td>
               <td width="100%" style="text-align:left;">
                <div style="">
                 <p>
                  <span style="color: #9c800d; font-family: helvetica;"><strong>10:00AM - 2:00PM</strong></span>
                 </p>
                </div>
               </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
               <td>
                <div style="">
                <p>
                 <span style="color: #9c800d; font-family: helvetica;text-transform:uppercase;"><strong>location:</strong></span>
                </p>
                </div>
               </td>
               <td width="100%" style="text-align:left;">
                <div style="">
                 <p>
                  <span style="color: #9c800d; font-family: helvetica;line-height:1.5;"><strong>Fort Rucker Army Installation<br/>Bldg.4502, Room 303</strong></span>
                 </p>
                </div>
               </td>
              </tr>
              
             </tbody>
            </table>
           </td>
           <td width="35%" style="text-align:right;">
            <div>
             <img src="http://enews.trident.edu/hs-fs/hub/336281/file-2668017528-jpg/images/Outreach/James_Shiver_175px.jpg?t=1446144504152" width="100%">
            </div>
            <p style="text-align:left;" color="#ffffff" align="left"><span style="font-family: helvetica; color: #ffffff;" color="#ffffff"><strong>James Shiver</strong></span><br/><span style="font-family: helvetica; font-size: 13px; color: #ffffff;">334-470-9146</span><br><a href="mailto:james.shiver@trident.edu" style="text-decoration:none;" data-hs-link-id="0" target="_blank"><span style="color: #ffffff;">james.shiver@trident.edu</span></a></p>
           </td>
          </tr>
         </tbody>
        </table>
        <table style="border-spacing;0px;border-collapse:collapse;background-color:rgb(0,39,77);" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
         <tbody>
          <tr>
          <td width="20"></td>
           <td width="80">
            <div style="border-top:2px solid #9c800d;width:98%">
             <p style="color:#ffffff;text-align:center;font-family:helvetica;font-weight:bold;">
              Can't stop by? Visit us Online:
             </p>
            </div>
           </td>
          <td width="20"></td>  
          </tr>
         </tbody>
        </table>
        <table style="border-spacing;0px;border-collapse:collapse;background-color:rgb(0,39,77);text-align:center;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center">
         <tr>
          <td width="20"></td>
          <td>
           <div>
            <p style="text-align:center;color:#ffffff;font-family:helvetica;font-size:14px;">
             <a href="../www.trident.edu/james" style="color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none;font-size:14px;" target="_blank">trident.edu/james</a>
            </p>
           </div>
          </td>
          <td width="">
           <div>
            <p style="text-align:center;color:#ffffff;font-family:helvetica;font-size:14px;">
             <a href="http://www.trident.edu/news-and-events?cid=701E00000007j5C" style="color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none;font-size:14px;" target="_blank">News and Events</a>
            </p>
           </div>
          </td>
          <td>
           <div>
            <p style="text-align:center;color:#ffffff;font-family:helvetica;font-size:14px;">
             <a href="http://blog.trident.edu?cid=701E00000007j5C" style="color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none;font-size:14px;" target="_blank">University Blog</a>
            </p>
           </div>
          </td>
          <td width="20"></td>
         </tr>
          
        </table>
        <table style="border-spacing;0px;border-collapse:collapse;background-color:rgb(0,39,77);" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
         <tbody>
          <tr>
           <td width="20"></td>
           <td width="60">
            <div>
             <p style="color:#ffffff;text-align:center;font-family:helvetica;font-weight:bold;">
              Trident University<br/>1212 Plaza Dr.<br/>Cypress, CA 90630
             </p>
            </div>
           </td>
           <td width="20"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td width="20"></td>
           <td width="60">
            <div>
             <img src="http://enews.trident.edu/hs-fs/hub/336281/file-2102317013-png/outreach_emblem-188px.png?t=1446144504152&amp;width=80&amp;name=outreach_emblem-188px.png" width="80" align="center">
            </div>
           </td>
           <td width="20"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td width="20"></td>
           <td width="60"><p style="color:#ffffff;font-size:13px"><a href="#" style="color:#ffffff;">Unsubscribe</a></p></td>
           <td width="20"></td>
          </tr>
         </tbody>
        </table>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nancy, we have are working on a series of articles that will guide you through the ins and outs of modern HTML email coding. 

Check out the introductory post 
http://blog.edmdesigner.com/modern-html-email-tutorial/ 

And here's the first piece as well 
http://blog.edmdesigner.com/the-basics-of-html-and-css-part-one/ 

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

**You need to include an `!important` in the media query in the `<style>` so that it can override the inline styles in the email body.** This allows table cells to became full width and stack on small viewports.

Here is a basic example of responsive 2-column email layout using media queries:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <!-- META Stuff -->
    <!-- CSS Reset -->
    <style>
        /* Media Queries */
        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            .email-container {
                width: 100% !important;
                margin: auto !important;
            }
            /* What it does: Forces table cells into full-width rows. */
            .stack-column {
                display: block !important;
                width: 100% !important;
                max-width: 100% !important;
                direction: ltr !important;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body width="100%" bgcolor="#000000" style="margin: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">
    <center style="width: 100%; background: #000000;">
        <!-- Email Body : BEGIN -->
        <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="600" style="margin: auto;" class="email-container">
            <!-- 2 Even Columns : BEGIN -->
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 10px;">
                    <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <!-- Column : BEGIN -->
                            <td class="stack-column">
                                <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px; color: #555555; padding: 0 10px 10px; text-align: left;">
                                            Column 1 Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. 
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                            <!-- Column : END -->
                            <!-- Column : BEGIN -->
                            <td class="stack-column">
                                <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px; color: #555555; padding: 0 10px 10px; text-align: left;">
                                            Column 2 Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. 
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                            <!-- Column : END -->
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- 2 Even Columns : END -->
        </table>
    </center>
</body>
```

[Full code available here](https://github.com/TedGoas/Cerberus/blob/master/cerberus-responsive.html)